Unable to read File in spark , which contains ":" in file name.(Java)
File path : /home/admin/Parquet/DumpData/LC0:TCProfile.parquet
I am getting below Error
`your org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=file:/home/admin/Parquet/DumpData/LC0:TCProfile.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=42694; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFooterForFileError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:521)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: .LC0:TCProfile.parquet.crc
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.getChecksumFile(ChecksumFileSystem.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:976)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.newStream(HadoopInputFile.java:69)`

I need to read files into Spark and process the datasets, but I’m encountering exceptions when the file names contain colons (:). Since I don’t have permission to rename these files, I need an alternative solution to handle this issue.

Try to create as symlink of that file with some better name, or you can use the Hadoop  Path Class to Read this.

Hadoop path class also getting same exception
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path path = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(filePath);
Dataset df = spark.read().parquet(path.toString());
symlink creation is working. but , is any other options are there, other than symlink creation ?
